# How to tune a Catboost Regressor

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, catboost

I have been trying to study about hyperparameter tuning for CatBoost regressor for my regression problem. The only issue being I can't figure out what all parameters should I tune for my use case out of the sea of parameters available for CatBoost. I am unable to find any helpful sources that would guide me through the selection of parameters to be tuned. So I would be appreciative to hear how do people usually choose the parameters they want to tune for their models and what is the thought process behind that?